# How to figure out the system dependency of BeautifulSoup in PyCharm?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I tried to extract data from websites. To do so, I installed BeautifulSoup4 in my PyCharm (educational edition and Community edition on Windows10 Professional). However, I am unable to load BeautifulSoup even though I restarted my computer and PyCharm. Below are the error messages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning\venv\py3.8\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-f33cf0cb8fd3>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning\venv\py3.8\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning\venv\py3.8\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 509, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning\venv\py3.8\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_html5lib.py", line 20, in <module>
    import html5lib
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\DeepLearning\venv\py3.8\lib\site-packages\html5lib\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

My system environments:

```
Windows 10 Professional
Mobile station ThinkPad P50
PyCharm Educational Edition 2020.3
Python3.8
```

I can run BeautifulSoup on Linux server, but am unable to do so on my PyCharm. Any further help and advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just don't use Windows.

Comment: :( It is hard for me to replace my mobile station now. Any other advice?

Comment: Try to start a new project with a new `venv`. If this doesn't help, either go Linux or run a VM with Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It does work now.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for @baduker.

Following his advice, I created a new project with a new venv. This issue has been fixed. Thanks to @baduker.